# Listbox scrollbars not visible in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, scrollbar, visibility

I cannot view the vertical scroll bar for Listbox control in WP7. I have set the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible". 
Can someone suggest solution for it.

Thanks and Regards,
Kanaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is becuase your listbox itsn't filled with enough items for showing the right side scroll bar. When you have enough items in your listbox so theres not enough space for showing more items on one view without scrolling the rightside scrollbar will showup. I personally think that this is kinda confusing so don't feel lame. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as scrollbars in Windows Phone 7. There isn't even an indicator that the view is scrollable or extends beyond the visible part. Your useer will have to find out themselves.

The *ScrollbarVisiblity* properties have probably been inherited from other environments where scrollbars exist.

Comment: Thats strange, as I can see many apps on Wp7 display scrollbar on right hand side of the Listbox. Than how can i display it? Any idea.

Comment: Do you mean the grayish, partially transparent line along the right border that appears while scrolling and disappears when the scrolling stops?

Comment: Yes, Atleast If I can show that is also fine.So that the user can visualize that he has too scroll down too much.